# How to access docker imaged influxdb

Tags: docker, influxdb

Environment: WINDOWS10 + DOCKER

I already setup docker in WINDOWS10, and could run the image by the command:
docker run -d -p 8086:8086 -p 2003:2003 -e INFLUXDB_GRAPHITE_ENABLED=true influxdb

Would I know how to access this indfluxdb? I mean, I could similiar run the command:
influx -precision rfc3339

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `docker exec` at PowerShell or CMD. Example:

1. Open PowerShell or CMD,
2. typing: `docker exec <influxdb_container_name> influx -precision rfc3339`

You can get `<influxdb_container_name>` through `docker ps|grep influxdb`